# Binding Tooltip to two properties in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Currently I have something like this and it works fine:

```
ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding PersonInfo}"
```

But I also have another property called `PersonDetails`

I want to be able to make the `tooltip` to show both of them and not just the first one.
Something like `PersonInfo + "\r\n" + PersonDetails`

Where should I start from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sweat, you didn't specify WPF or SL but the concept is the same for each. Something like this should work just fine for your requirements;

```
<Object>
 <ToolTipService.ToolTip>

      <TextBlock>
           <Run Text="{Binding PersonInfo}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
           <Run Text="{Binding PersonDetails}"/>
      </TextBlock>

  </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Object>
```

Which also provides you the ability to format that information you're showing in different ways and even style it up a bit if you want, like if you wanted to make part of it `Bold` like in the example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, what is "Run" in the text blocks for ?

Comment: It's just a way of separating sections within the same inline class, or to make it simple, so you can do multiple things like that in one single `TextBlock` instead of having individual `TextBlock` for each and having to embed them in a `StackPanel` or `Grid` or something. Basically just cuts your object tree down a bit.

Comment: @DevWannaBe sweet, you aren't one of my interns are ya? lol, I'm (well as of next week) based in KC

Comment: @ChrisW +1 For learning something new! Great answer, i've since removed mine!

Comment: Unfortunately you can't bind on runs (or anything else within text blocks) as their properties aren't dependency properties. You will have to change this solution to use multiple text blocks in stack panels or some such.

Comment: @John, you sure about that?

Comment: @ChrisW. Apparently I was mistaken - very odd, I felt quite sure about it and have worked around that perceived limitation a number of times. Now I'm not sure where I got that idea from. Thanks for correcting me.